# How do you install Python's Wheezy.web microframework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wheezy-web

I tried following the documentation, which can be found here: (https://pythonhosted.org/wheezy.web/gettingstarted.html) but I'm too dumb to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Install
Wheezy Web requires python version 2.4 to 2.7 or 3.2+. It is independent of operating system. You can install it from pypi site using setuptools:

```
$ easy_install wheezy.web
```

If you are using virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv env
$ env/bin/easy_install wheezy.web
```

Since Wheezy Web is template engine agnostic, you need specify extra

requirements (per template engine of your choice):

```
$ env/bin/easy_install wheezy.web[jinja2]
$ env/bin/easy_install wheezy.web[mako]
$ env/bin/easy_install wheezy.web[tenjin]
$ env/bin/easy_install wheezy.web[wheezy.template]
```

Develop
You can get the source code using mercurial:

```
$ hg clone http://bitbucket.org/akorn/wheezy.web
$ cd wheezy.web
```

Prepare virtualenv environment in env directory

```
$ make env
```

... and run all tests:

```
$ make test
```

You can read how to compile from source code different versions of python in the article published on mind reference blog.

You can run certain make targets with specific python version. Here we are going to run doctest with python3.2:

```
$ make env doctest-cover VERSION=3.2
```

Generate documentation with sphinx:

```
$ make doc
```

Source: https://pythonhosted.org/wheezy.web/gettingstarted.html#install

Answer (score 0):

If it's still actual, you can install wheezy.web just via pip: `pip install wheezy.web wheezy.template`